# How to use stdin pipe with fsharpi (fsi) and mono

Tags: .net, linux, f#, mono

i am using fsharpi (fsi) as background compiling process using System.Diagnostics.Process to spawn the process. My ProcessStartInfo Setup looks like:

```
let psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
psi.UseShellExecute <- false
if System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform = PlatformID.Unix
    then
        psi.FileName <- "/usr/bin/mono"
        psi.Arguments <- "/usr/lib/fsharp/fsi.exe"
    else
        psi.FileName <- @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\fsi.exe"
        psi.Arguments <- ""
psi.WorkingDirectory <- "some workdir"
psi.CreateNoWindow <- true
psi.RedirectStandardError <- true
psi.RedirectStandardInput <- true
psi.RedirectStandardOutput <- true
```

my Process is created like:

```
let proc = Process.Start(psi)
```

afterwards i use stdin to emit my code:

```
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(myCode+";;"+Environment.NewLine)
proc.StandardInput.Flush()
```

this works on Windows 7 with VisualStudio with standard setup - unfortunately it does not work on linux (ubuntu 11.04, Mono JIT compiler version 2.6.7 (Debian 2.6.7-5ubuntu3), F#, Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Interactive build 2.0.0.0) [Note: same for mono 2.10 built from source].
Anyhow StandardOutput works on both platforms just fine.

EDIT: to clarify how/what does not work: after receiving standard startup output (F#, Microsoft (R) F#...) i send some code (lets say let foo x = x * 2) via redirected input stream. The answer is received synchronously (in another thread) using redirected output (using proc.StandardOut.ReadLine() but ReadLine never returns!

I suspect it is a problem with (the extra process) mono in which fsharpi is running or a platform issue (newline etc).

To rule out the second possibility i tried manual pipes. To do so i created a file with content:

```
"#quit;;[NEWLINE]"
```

whereby [NEWLINE stands for Unix endlines and windows style EOL]

using following command (windows):

```
fsi.exe < thefileDescribedAbove
```

or respectively (linux)

```
fsharpi < thefileDescribedAbove
```

like expected it works on Windows (opens FSI and quits immediately) but stalls on linux (like ;; or NEWLINE is not received).
Given the strange result in this test i suspect a more fundamental problem with my approach (hopefully not).

thanks a lot

Comment: Why are you trying to use `fsi` and not compile the code using `fsc`?

Comment: actually i am not compiling fsharp code in order to execute it - the host process runs my own compiler (in fsi) for another language. With fsi i get interactive development for my language for free.

Comment: If don't run the F# code, what are you doing with it?

Comment: well. my app is a simple IDE - in the FSI instance i got some compiler services running (also the whole environment which is built up incrementally). I pass source code in via stdin, convert it to AST via quotations, compile it into another language using the whole environment in fsi - afterwards i read it back via stdout. of course it would be possible to spawn a compiler thread each time the user submits new code - nevertheless this is wasteful because i like the incremental environment provided by fsi.

Comment: I don't think there is anything fundamentally wrong with your approach - see the source code for MonoDevelop integration which does similar thing and works just fine: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/blob/master/src/Services/InteractiveSession.fs. Can you clarify in what way does your code "not work"?

Comment: thanks tomas, edit above. I just reduced the problem to a minimal test program available at: [link](http://pastebin.com/xxrGHTYf). The Windows output is: [link](http://pastebin.com/hyqNReSc) in contrast to windows (missing let binding output): [link](http://pastebin.com/ASnXwNQQ)

Comment: @h_s Hmm - I don't really see any difference between your code and MonoDevelop plugin. Could you try listening on `ErrorDataReceived`? (In case FSI terminates because of some error)

Comment: stderr is quiet. very very strange. if i run the script in another fsi shell directly on linux (on another machine) i get the missing line after pressing an arbitrary key. something strange is going on here apparently.

Comment: FSI can't read from stdin for me to (only under mono, windows is fine) why not just create a temp file and use --use to compile it?

Comment: You are using `WriteLine` method and also passing the new line character. Can you just try `WriteLine` without appending the new line character?

Comment: @Ankur @h_s - You could also try using `Write` with `\n` (which is what MonoDevelop plugin does...)

Comment: @jpalmer: not an acceptable solution for me because i need the incremental (REPL) style of fsi. i dont want to start a process each the the user enters some code. @Ankur/Tomas: i have tried all possible variants of Write(c+"\n"), Write(c+"\r\n"). I looked into fsi source but could not find an indication what the problem is. To me its a micracle how this code works in MonoDevelop.

Comment: @tomas: my current working monodevelop still runs in .net3.* with F# 1.9.9 (i suspect). Is it possible the problem was introduced in Interactive build 2.0.0.0? (It seems NOT to be a mono problem which i discovered after some tests)

Comment: fail - Just tried it with 1.9.9 - same problem.

Comment: I think that you may be able to have some better luck using Fifo's (named pipes), it looks a bit more promising

Comment: @h_s - I'm pretty sure this is just some stupid error, but it is really hard to find out! Does your code work if you execute some other .NET application (e.g. if you write simple echo app that just prints what it gets as an input?)

Comment: yes it works with a simple mono echo application. currently i am investigating the problem in fsi source ;-). @jpalmer: unfortunately i have to use stdin - otherwise it is not possible to use fsi like i want to....

Comment: interesting: the fsi process seems to do some kind of busy waiting - it needs lots of cpu and seems to stall in: (gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00b29416 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x001d1df6 in poll () from /lib/libc.so.6
...??? frames ommitted...
#17 0x080609b8 in mono_jit_runtime_invoke (method=
    "Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell:MainMain ()", obj=0x0, params=
    0xbf925c3c, exc=0x0) at mini.c:5746

Comment: Done!! --readline- argument fixes the problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a long senseless bughunt: "--readline-" argument to fsi fixes the problem! thanks to all tracking this down :-)

(actually i tried this a long time ago - apparently i messed something up with my test at that time)